# Looong time to load 18.04.2

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I just installed Debian and have ubuntu 18.04.2 on another partition. It used to take ubuntu 40 seconds or so to load but now takes almost 3 minutes.
My dim (80 year old memory) tells me that the uuid of the swap partition can be changed by a new installation and the existing installations can take a long time to work around this during boot.If that is the cause can I correct it? If it's not the cause what can I do?

Per request:

```
john@john-OptiPlex-780:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 57.402s
└─multi-user.target @1min 57.402s
  └─kerneloops.service @1min 40.283s +11ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 40.281s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 35.377s +4.903s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 31.866s +3.509s
          └─dbus.service @1min 31.776s
            └─basic.target @1min 31.772s
              └─sockets.target @1min 31.772s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 31.770s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 31.754s
                    └─cryptsetup.target @15.948s
                      └─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @1.660s
                        └─-.mount @1.657s
                          └─system.slice @1.660s
                            └─-.slice @1.657s
```

---

```
john@john-OptiPlex-780:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=f68d7190-f844-4236-af0c-8ca058df937e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=19be91fa-9600-4851-896b-64ffc12bb07e none            swap    sw              0       0
john@john-OptiPlex-780:~$ blkid
```

sudo bklid produced:

```
john@john-OptiPlex-780:~$ sudo blkid 
[sudo] password for john: 
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="5ACCB5047A8E203D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="abd411b6-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="2921846b-0788-49e4-b81e-0afb576dd1a7" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="abd411b6-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="76EBD1DC0B897C49" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="abd411b6-06"
/dev/sda7: UUID="f68d7190-f844-4236-af0c-8ca058df937e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="abd411b6-07"
/dev/sda8: UUID="0db17b41-cb8f-4f6e-9016-657ca5ba0590" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="abd411b6-08"
/dev/sda9: UUID="c246fcaa-bedd-4162-a30d-d0762b7fd968" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="abd411b6-09"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Comment: Please open a terminal window and execute `sytemd-analyze critical-chain` and copy the output to paste into your question - this will help determine what is holding up boot.  You should also include the outputs of `cat /etc/fstab`, and `blkid` to that you can check if the UUID of the swap partition matches what is in fstab

Comment: Couldn't find a way to post the results requested so had to add them in edit of original post. As you can see "blkid" didn't produce anything, perhaps I misunderstood your request

Comment: "# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=19be91fa-9600-4851-896b-64ffc12bb07e none            swap    sw              0       0" DOES THAT MEAN THAT YOU MUST CHANGE SWAP PARTITION TO "SWAPOFF BEFORE AN INSTALLATION?"

Comment: AHA! The new (Debian) installation boots in about 40 seconds. The SWAP uuid appears to be the issue.

Comment: Yes it does appear that the UUID of the swap partition was changed during the installation of the New OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same partition was used as swap space for both distros - the UUID of the partition was changed during the installation of the second distro.

To solve this you need to copy the UUID shown in the output of `blkid` for /dev/sda5, and place that information into /etc/fstab, in the line below the command "# swap was on ..."

To do this I would

- open two terminal windows
- In the first window, enter the command `blkid | grep sda5`
- In the second window enter the command `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`
- In the second window, enter the command `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
- In the first window, highlight the numbers which make up the UUID: "2921846b-0788-49e4-b81e-0afb576dd1a7" - press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the UUID
- In the second window, use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the bad uuid, and use the delete / backspace keys to delete that uuid.
- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste the new UUID in place.  Press press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and exit the editor.

Comment: Thank you VERY much - I got almost all the way BUT "Press press ctrl+o and then ctrl+x to save and exit the editor." didn't save and exit

Comment: WELL! I looked at fstab in etc and the change has been made. ALL IS OK - Thank you Charles

Comment: The original installation just booted up in less than 40 seconds.

Comment: @JohnSaleeby Were you using nano as the editor?  I like that one because it's intuitive for me - I need to learn to use vim though.

Comment: @JohnSaleeby If the answer posted help, please consider marking this as accepted - it will help other users find answers that have helped people.

Comment: "@JohnSaleeby If the answer posted help, please consider marking this as accepted - it will help other users find answers that have helped people. – Charles Green " If I knew how I most certainly will. Yes I used nano.Thanks again

Comment: @JohnSaleeby At the top of my answer, you should find a little check mark, and a pair of up/down arrows.  The Check mark accepts the answer, and the up/down arrows are used to upvote (or downvote) a question or answer.